# sum of the array using pointers in c

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, pointers, while-loop

Finding sum of the array elements using pointers using following code.
i dont know why program is not ending at the end of the array!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(a) (int) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])) 

int sum_array(int * , int);

int main(void){

    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    printf("Array length %d\n",LEN(a));

    int sum = sum_array(a,LEN(a));

    printf("Sum of array is %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
int sum_array( int * p , int n){

    int sum = 0;

    while ( p < p+n ){
        printf("Sum of array is %d\n",sum);
        sum += *p++;
    }

    return sum;
}
`
```

SOLVED GUYS thanks!!

```
int sum_array( int * a , int n){
    int sum = 0, *p=a;
    while ( p < a+n ){
        printf("Sum of array is %d\n",sum);
        sum += *p++;
    }
    return sum;
```

getting address boundary error!!

Comment: You increase `p` in each iteration of the loop, making the result of `p + n` a moving target.

Answer (score 4):

How can `p < p + n` ever be 1 for a non-negative `n`?

You need to store the initial value of `p` somewhere if you want to bound the loop that way.

For an easy life use `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)` in place of `while (p < p + n)` and adopt, if you must and against any professional advice, a flashy version once you have the basics correct.

Comment: I'd say there's no flashier version than `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)`. That's what will impress other programmers the most!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that within the condition of the loop you are using the pointer that is changed within the loop.

```
while ( p < p+n ){
    printf("Sum of array is %d\n",sum);
    sum += *p++;
}
```

So the condition never will be equal to false except when `n` is equal to 0.

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
long long int sum_array( const int *p , size_t n );
```

Pay attention to that within the function the array is not changed. So the first parameter should have the qualifier const.

And

```
long long int sum_array( const int *p , size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;

    for ( const int *q = p; q < p + n; ++q )
    {
        sum += *q;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

If you want to use the while loop then the pointer q need to be defined outside the loop

```
    const int *q = p; 
    while ( q < p + n )
    {
        sum += *q++;
    }
```

Also do the following changes

```
#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))
```

and

```
printf("Array length %zu\n",LEN(a));

long long int sum = sum_array(a,LEN(a));

printf( "Sum of array is %lld\n",sum);
```

The type `long long int` is used for the variable `sum` because in general there can be an overflow.

Consider for example the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

int sum_array( const int * , size_t );

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { INT_MAX, 1 };

    printf("Array length %zu\n",LEN(a));

    int sum = sum_array( a, LEN( a ) );

    printf("Sum of array is %d\n",sum);

    return 0;
}

int sum_array( const int *p , size_t n )
{
    int sum = 0;    

    const int *q = p; 
    while ( q < p + n )
    {
        sum += *q++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Its output is

```
Array length 2
Sum of array is -2147483648
```

It is evident that the result is not what you are expecting.

If to make the type of the variable `sum` `long long int` then the result will be correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))

long long int sum_array( const int * , size_t );

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { INT_MAX, 1 };

    printf("Array length %zu\n",LEN(a));

    long long int sum = sum_array( a, LEN( a ) );

    printf("Sum of array is %lld\n",sum);

    return 0;
}

long long int sum_array( const int *p , size_t n )
{
    long long int sum = 0;  

    const int *q = p; 
    while ( q < p + n )
    {
        sum += *q++;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The program output is

```
Array length 2
Sum of array is 2147483648
```